# Correct usage of word potent

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

*Potent* means having great power, influence or effect. I want to know if my usage of *potent* is correct.

> *The government needs to find a **potent** solution to this problem.*
>
> *His teaching method is **potent** and unique, that is the reason students like to attend his lecture.*

Potent is something effective and powerful. Is *potent* a correct adjective in these sentences or some other suitable adjective can supplant this adjective?

Comment: There are certainly other words that could be used. But it would be up to you if you wanted to use something else or not.

Comment: I'm not fond of Sentence #2, but it has nothing to do with the word _potent_. I'd recommend: _Students like to attend his lecture because his teaching methods are potent and unique._ If the original wording was preserved, I'd recommend a semicolon in place of the comma.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a word that fits but isn't perhaps *commonly* used in that context you can create a sentence that has more power behind it. When I see an "interesting" use of a word it often makes me pause and think, sometimes re-read it. So long as it isn't completely wrong and out of context!

"Potent" does mean something effective and powerful, so you are in effect saying "*a powerful and effective solution to this problem*".

I've got no problem with the word choice. I have heard the *antonym* of "potent" - "*impotent*" - used frequently when talking about politics, [this BBC News article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-17547159) for example sees the UK government called "impotent" and arguing why they are not.

Comment: This is a good word usage philosophy.